# @Html.CheckBoxFor adding a free text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, switchery

I got an HTML file from design with following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-switchery checked name="product_edit_active_control" id="product_edit_active_control" />
```

how to create this using MVC's `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model =>` I know how to add a new attribute using e.g. `new { @class = "longInputForEdit" }`

but how to add non attribute in my case **data-switchery**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property, new { @class="", data_switchery=""})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `new { @class = "longInputForEdit", data_switchery="attr value" }`
complete example:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class="", data_switchery="attribute value"})
```

so you could use `_` for any attribute with `-` in it like
`some_val` will be `some-val`